# iverilog : Can't find task randomize in class Packet

Tags: system-verilog, iverilog

I am new to System Verilog, and I was trying out some code where I am trying to randomize a 3-bit bus.
The code goes like this:

```
class Packet;
    rand bit [2:0]data;
endclass

module top_tb;

initial
begin
    Packet pkt = new();
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    begin
        pkt.randomize();
        $display("Itr = %0d, Data value = %0d",i, pkt.data);
    end
end
endmodule
```

I am using `iverilog` for simulating the above code, but getting the following errors:

```
tb4.sv:12: error: Can't find task randomize in class Packet
tb4.sv:12: error: Enable of unknown task ``pkt.randomize''.
```

I think `randomize` is an inbuilt function in SystemVerilog and should not need explicit definition in the class. So, I am not sure how to proceed with this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think `randomize` is an inbuilt function in SystemVerilog and should
> not need explicit definition in the class.

You are correct.

Your code works on different simulators like VCS and Cadence on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/LfWC).

When I try your code with `iverilog`, I get different errors.

It may be that these versions of `iverilog` do not support that SystemVerilog syntax.  You either need to find different ways to do what you are doing that is supported by `iverilog`, or you need to use a simulator that supports the code you have.